# How to append all the arrays inside a list into a single array combined by the depth in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list which contains a variable amount of [n,1,2] numpy arrays. I need a way of combining all those arrays into one [n+however many,1,2] arrays.

I have tried to create a loop with an empty array and then using dstack to sort of combine them. But I have to 1) predefine the size of the array in advance which won't do as I do not know it 2) The array has values that I must overwrite and thus dstack dosen't work too well. Is there a more elegant and easier solution?

I have to use an array of this particular setup as I must pass it on to a method that I have not wrote that requires it.

Comment: `np.concatenate(list_of_arrays, axis=0)`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.concatenate`.

```
>>> arrays = [np.zeros((3, 1, 2)) for _ in range(3)]
>>> np.concatenate(arrays, axis=0).shape
(9, 1, 2)
```